# How can i sort a Meteor Collection by Period of time?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

How can i sort by period of time in a Meteor Collection:

Example:

```
{ "_id" : "84zCkAixjYwADiSQc", "time" : "8:00 – 8:20"}
{ "_id" : "87zC453AixjAD1läs", "time" : "8:30 – 8:45"}
{ "_id" : "22zCkAix44wADiSQc", "time" : "8:45 – 9:20"}
{ "_id" : "87zCkAi5jYwADiSQc", "time" : "9:00 – 10:20"}
```

mongo sort doesn't work.

Comment: Can you [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33341863/edit) your post to include the code that you have tried to for doing the sort? Your `_id`s are not unique.

Comment: the `time` should be a valid JS date so you can use the built in operator from MongoDB :)

Comment: If you are going to continue to use a string as the "time" value, you can simply sort on that, if you want to go from earliest to latest, or vice vers (sort descending); however, you would need to use "military time" (22:00 for 10 pm, etc.) for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collection.find({},{sort:{time: 1}}).fetch();`

would sort by the time string, alphabetically. Problems will come for times after noon, however. If you want something more than that, I'd suggest breaking `time` up into `start-time` and `end-time` and storing them in military time with leading 0s, as @B.ClayShannon suggested.